# Same code different plot in qplot vs ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get very different results, the code should be equivalent?

```
qplot(x = price, data = diamonds) + facet_wrap(~cut)
```

vs

```
ggplot(aes(x = diamonds$price), data = diamonds) + geom_histogram()  + facet_wrap(~cut)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead

```
ggplot(aes(x = price), data = diamonds) + geom_histogram()  + facet_wrap(~cut)
```

Comment: Exactly, `$` has no place inside `aes` since ggplot2 does non-standard evaluation. It looks for variables inside the declared `data`.